# iteracion sobre lista en python y seleccionar numeros contiguos

Tags: python

como podria seleccionar de una lista los numeros continuos y agregarlos en otra lista?.
por ejemeplo de la lista se seleccione : [1,2] porque son los unicos elementos que estan seguidos.

y como podria para añadir a la lista por ejemplo dos numeros con un  salto entre ellos? (en el ejemplo de la lista seria el 15 y el 17, puesto que hay un salta de un numero)

````
lista = [1, 2, 8, 12, 15,17]
contiguos = []


for elemento in lista:

    numeros_contiguos = lista[elemento:elemento+1]
    print(numeros_contiguos)
    if elemento == numeros_contiguos:
        contiguos.append(elemento)```

graciass
````

Answer (score 2):

Bueno para eso creo que seria mejor utilizae un ciclo `for x in range(num)`, para asi poder acceder a los elementos de la lista.

```py
lista = [1, 2, 8, 12, 15,17]
contiguos = []

#iteramos en el rango del tamaño de la lista -1
for element in range(len(lista)-1):
    #un numero es contiguo con otro si sumado o restado 1 son iguales
    if lista[element] == lista[element+1]-1:
        contiguos.append((lista[element],lista[element+1]))
print(contiguos)
```

Lo que hacemos es iterar en el rango del tamaño de la lista -1, esto para evitar errores ya que accedemos a la posición siguiente de la lista con `element+1`, al cual luego le restamos 1 para saber si son iguales.
También podemos hacerlo en una lista anidada agregando un ciclo `for` mas.

```py
#lista = [1, 2, 8, 12, 15,17]
contiguos = []

listas = [[1,2,7,9],[3,4,9,9,4]]

for lista in listas:                  
    for element in range(len(lista)-1):
        if lista[element] == lista[element+1]-1:
            contiguos.append((lista[element],lista[element+1]))
print(contiguos)
#salida ->  [(1,2),(3,4)]
```

Puedes hacerlo de forma "dinámica" (que itere una vez mas si hay sub listas o no) poniendo algunas cosas dentro de una función o hacer una función recursiva, aunque la recursividad no es buena en todo caso.

Comment: graciasss...y si tuviera una lista anidada? por ejemplo: lista_dos = [[1, 2, 8, 12, 15], [17, 18, 32, 34]]

Comment: Lo siento me demore, estuve ocupado, el ejemplo ya fue añadido

Comment: @ANTONIOBENITEZ deberías hacer una nueva pregunta con lo que pides de las listas anidadas en lugar de incluir modificaciones a la pregunta en los comentarios. Ten en cuenta que se puede dar el caso de que alguien cambie su respuesta en función de cosas nuevas que pones y la pregunta-respuesta ya tengan nada que ver.

Comment: Hola me referia a seleccionar los contiguos dentro de una lista anidada pero refiriendome a los contiguos que hay relacionados con  dos sublista. Por ejemplo lista=[[1,4,8],[3,10,15]]....en este caso los contiguos y la salida que estoy buscando es [(3,4)]

Comment: @ANTONIOBENITEZ Hoo.. Bueno ahi cambia la cosa, pero en tu pregunta no das el ejemplo de una lista anidad, mi respuesta responde a tu pregunta de *"como saber los numeros contiguos en una lista"*

Comment: @ANTONIOBENITEZ puedes editar tu pregunta **añadiendo** otro ejemplo de la lista anidada ó hacer otra pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Una versión usando comprehensión y [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
lista = [1, 2, 8, 12, 15, 17]
sep = 1 # Distancia entre numeros
contiguos = [x for x in zip(lista, lista[1:]) if x[1]-x[0] == sep]
```

Comment: Este ejemplo funciona con números si están consecutivos en la lista inicial. Si por ejemplo `sep = 5` no te va a devolver `12` y `17`. Aún así buena respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas que te devuelva los números aunque estos no estén consecutivos en `lista`, puedes hacerlo de esta forma basada en la respuesta de @aeportugal:

```
from itertools import combinations

lista = [1, 2, 8, 12, 15, 17]
sep = 7
separados_sep = [n for n in combinations(lista, 2) if abs(n[0] - n[1]) == sep]
```

En este caso para `sep = 7` devolvería `[(1, 8), (8, 15)]`

Comment: Hola Antonio, la respuesta que he dado es en relación a la pregunta que pone en la página, en la que no hablas de listas anidadas. Cómo te puse en los comentarios de la respuesta de Christian, si vas a modificar tanto la pregunta deberías hacer una nueva, no pasa nada.

Comment: Imagina que modificas tu pregunta y la cambias a lo que pides de las listas anidadas... Habría respuestas que te dieron a tu pregunta inicial y que nada tienen que ver con la pregunta nueva. O por el contrario imagina que no la cambias y que te respondemos a lo de las listas anidadas de los comentarios... En el futuro alguien que entre con tu misma duda no entenderá la respuesta que se te da a menos que se lea todos los comentarios de las respuestas.